# How to change btn-group colors individually and exclusively?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio

I need to make a rating button group 0 to 5, and change only the color of the selected rating (I want each rating to have a different color) and switch back to white the button if other rating is selected.

```
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." id="Rating">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">5</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Add another css class for each of the buttons.. e.g. `class="btn btn-default color-class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some inputs on how you could approach this case:

> I want each rating to have a different color

Approach would be to give each `button` element the `style` (*using class for example*) that we wish to.

Sample code snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." id="Rating">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-info">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-warning">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger">5</button>
</div>
```

---

> switch back to white the button if other rating is selected.

If I understand correctly, all `button` should have a *base (or default)* color and upon some  *action* (clicking another button in the group, the currently selected would default back to it's *base color*, whereas the clicked upon `button` should *highlight* based on its color).

There are two approaches - `JavaScript` based or `CSS` only.

---

**There are pros and cons**

*JavaScript based*: easily maintainable, readable.

*CSS based*: more code, maintainability is difficult (based on how many buttons are in the group).

---

Here is a sample JavaScript approach:

```js
$(".btn-group > button").on("click", function() {

  var defaultClass = "btn btn-default";
  var toBeAssignedClass = $(this).attr("data-btn-class");

  $(".btn-group > button").attr("class", defaultClass);
  $(this).attr("class", toBeAssignedClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." id="Rating">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-default">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-primary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-success">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-info">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-warning">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-btn-class="btn btn-danger">5</button>
</div>
```

---

Here is a sample CSS approach:

```css
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='1']:hover,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='1']:focus, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='1']:active, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='1'].active {
  background-color: #265a88;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #265a88 100%);
}
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='2']:hover,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='2']:focus, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='2']:active, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='2'].active {
  background-color: #419641;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #419641 100%);
}
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='3']:hover,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='3']:focus, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='3']:active, 
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='3']:hover:active {
  background-color: #2aabd2;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #2aabd2 100%);
}
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='4']:hover,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='4']:focus,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='4']:active,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='4']:hover:active {
  background-color: #eb9316;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #eb9316 100%);
}
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='5']:hover,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='5']:focus,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='5']:active,
div.btn-group > button[data-rating='5']:hover:active {
  background-color: #c12e2a;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0, #c12e2a 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." id="Rating">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="3">3</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-rating="5">5</button>
</div>
```